# Ruby on Rails Changing routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to understand what to do with that.

in config/routes.rb  (I open it with **Notepad++**) I write

> get '/messages' => 'messages#index'

(actually it doesn't matter what code is exactly).

After writing this, in app/controllers there must be **"messages_controller.rb"** but there isn't.

There is nothing wrong with code I think its need to push app/controller that I wrote something in routes.rb but I don't know how.

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just run `rails g controller messages index` which will create all the files you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read Rails Routing Guide, there it is explained:
  [Rails Routing from the outside in](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Generally in the first part, you write the html method (get/post/...), then the url like '/messages' in your example and then where to point. In front of # there ist the name of the controller (that is why a controller messages_controller.rb is searched) and then after the # there must be the method in the controller. So your example searches for a method index in controller messages_controller.rb

If you want to genereate the controller use in your ruby command line somethink like

```
rails generate controller messages_controller index
```

This will create a controller with the method index.

Comment: thank you so much for not only solving problem but explanation. Again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
rails g controller Messages index
```